# Assigning functions to Objects

Tags: javascript

I want to add functions to JSON Objects, but I can't find function for assigning to all objects, only to one.

This code works with Arrays:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'random', {
    value: () => {
        return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
    },
});
```

I've also found this code:

```js
const obj = {name: 'Bob'};

obj.fullName = function() { return this.name }
```

But that one only works for specific object, not all of them.

Is it event possible to write global functions for all JSON Objects, and if is, then how to do it?

Comment: You can add properties on `Object.prototype` but i wouldn't recommend doing it.

Comment: Note that it's NOT recommended to change the global object prototypes. Also I want to note that the first block of code has a bug - the arrow function will not reference the correct `this`.

Comment: Another note: this has nothing to do with JSON. You're talking about JS object literals. JSON does not accept functions at all.

Comment: Are you aware that adding methods to all objects in JS means basically adding them to everything? Objects, primitives, functions, EVERYTHING; except of `null`, `undefined` and the few `Object.create(null)` you may have created. Maybe this is a teeny tiny bit overkill?

Answer (score 2):

You could add the `function` to `Object.prototype`. Note that this is not considered a very good practice because it could impact the rest of the code (like shown in the comments):

```js
Object.prototype.fullName = function() { return this.name; };

const obj = { name: 'Bob' };

console.log(obj.fullName());
```

You should consider doing this instead:

```js
const baseObject = { fullName: function() { return this.name; } };

const obj = Object.create(baseObject, { name: { value: 'Bob', writable: true } });

console.log(obj.fullName());
```

And if your target runtime (browser?) supports ECMAScript 6, you could also create a dedicated `class` for this:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  fullName() { return this.name; }
}

const bob = new MyClass('Bob');

console.log(bob.fullName());
```

Finally, the class syntax for ECMAScript 5:

```js
function MyClass(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

MyClass.prototype.fullName = function() { return this.name; }

const bob = new MyClass('Bob');

console.log(bob.fullName());
```

Comment: As for _"why shouldn't I do this?"_: `for (let prop in obj) { console.log(prop); }` -> "name", "fullName" (`fullName` will appear in any Object)

Comment: @blex in fairness, that's a known problem. `for..in` loops are usually a bad practice unless a) you *actually* want every property on the prototype chain b) you filter to only own properties. This has been the case for over two decades now. The bigger problem with adding stuff to the prototype is that you might clash with a native feature. Fun fact: that's why `.includes()` on strings/arrays is **not** called `.contains()`. The Mootools library had already added `.contains()` to the native prototype and the new method broke that. ES had to be amended.

Comment: @VLAZ I wouldn't use `for in` on an Object myself, but I've seen many people do it, because _usually it works_, so I think it's important to take that in consideration. Nice fact about `.contains`, I didn't know that!

Comment: @blex [just to drop a link for `.contains()`](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/having-a-non-enumerable-array-prototype-contains-may-not-be-web-compatible) because it's such a mess. Also, it's a shining example of why you want to avoid adding properties to an object. About `for..in` - it's not usually a problem, honestly. When I use it, I do want all properties. But that's honestly rare. `Object.keys`/`Object.entries` only gets the own properties and they are often more convenient to use anyway. I'd try to filter to only the properties I need when possible.